# When I click on my project Spring Tool suit generates following error log

Tags: java, spring-boot

I get this error when I clicking on Package of my project. I lastly installed hibernate tool and JPA tool

```
eclipse.buildId=3.8.2.201610040743-RELEASE-e46
java.version=1.8.0_101
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide -product org.springsource.sts.ide -product org.springsource.sts.ide -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide -product org.springsource.sts.ide -product org.springsource.sts.ide -data file:/E:/FALCON/ -product org.springsource.sts.ide

org.eclipse.jface
Error
Thu Nov 24 12:24:06 IST 2016
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jpt/jaxb/core/internal/InternalJaxbProjectManager$LocalExceptionHandler
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.InternalJaxbProjectManager.<init>(InternalJaxbProjectManager.java:161)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.InternalJaxbWorkspace.buildJaxbProjectManager(InternalJaxbWorkspace.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.InternalJaxbWorkspace.<init>(InternalJaxbWorkspace.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.plugin.JptJaxbCorePlugin.buildJaxbWorkspace(JptJaxbCorePlugin.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.plugin.JptJaxbCorePlugin.getJaxbWorkspace_(JptJaxbCorePlugin.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.plugin.JptJaxbCorePlugin.getJaxbWorkspace(JptJaxbCorePlugin.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.WorkspaceAdapterFactory.getJaxbWorkspace(WorkspaceAdapterFactory.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.WorkspaceAdapterFactory.getAdapter(WorkspaceAdapterFactory.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.WorkspaceAdapterFactory.getAdapter(WorkspaceAdapterFactory.java:36)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.adapter.AdapterFactoryProxy.getAdapter(AdapterFactoryProxy.java:82)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.AdapterManager.getAdapter(AdapterManager.java:294)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.PlatformObject.getAdapter(PlatformObject.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.context.PackageFragmentAdapterFactory.getJaxbWorkspace(PackageFragmentAdapterFactory.java:62)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.context.PackageFragmentAdapterFactory.getJaxbProjectManager(PackageFragmentAdapterFactory.java:57)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.context.PackageFragmentAdapterFactory.getJaxbProject(PackageFragmentAdapterFactory.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.context.PackageFragmentAdapterFactory.getJaxbPackage(PackageFragmentAdapterFactory.java:47)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.context.PackageFragmentAdapterFactory.getAdapter(PackageFragmentAdapterFactory.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.internal.context.PackageFragmentAdapterFactory.getAdapter(PackageFragmentAdapterFactory.java:34)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.AdapterManager.getAdapter(AdapterManager.java:323)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.AdapterManager.loadAdapter(AdapterManager.java:350)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.AdaptExpression.evaluate(AdaptExpression.java:93)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.IterateExpression.evaluate(IterateExpression.java:160)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.evaluate(EvaluationReference.java:72)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.evaluate(EvaluationReference.java:97)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.changed(EvaluationReference.java:91)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:114)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:343)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:358)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationService$1.changed(EvaluationService.java:76)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:114)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:343)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:358)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$4.changed(E4Application.java:801)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:114)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:343)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:358)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator$7.changed(SelectionAggregator.java:227)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:114)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:343)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:358)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionServiceImpl.setSelection(SelectionServiceImpl.java:31)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.selectionChanged(CompatibilityPart.java:450)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$1.run(Viewer.java:158)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:155)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2191)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1229)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:242)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$4(OpenStrategy.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:405)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

How could I resolve this error?

Comment: You have a problem with this plugin  " org.eclipse.jface "

Comment: yeah you are right.......